# Find a formula for the price of a derivative paying $\max(S_T(S_T-K),0)$

Tags: options, option-pricing, derivatives, brownian-motion, geometric-brownian

> Develop a formula for the price of a derivative paying
>
> $$\max(S_T(S_T-K))$$
>
> in the Black Scholes model.

Apparently the trick to this question is to compute the expectation under the stock measure. So,

$$\frac{C_0}{S_0} = \mathbb{E}[\frac{S_T\max{(S_T-K,0)}}{N_T}]$$

and taking $N_T = S_T$. We can split this expectation into two parts,

$$\mathbb{E}_{new}[\max(S_T-K,0)] = \mathbb{E}_{new}[S_T\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}] - \mathbb{E}_{new}[K\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}]$$

Focusing on the second term, we can show that the final stock price is distributed in the stock measure is,

$$ S_T = S_0 \exp{\{ (r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T +\sigma \sqrt{T} N(0,1) \}}\tag{1} $$

And then we have $\mathbb{E}_{new}[K\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}] = K \mathbb{P}(S_T > K) = K N(d_1)$.

Now concentrating on $\mathbb{E}_{new}[S_T\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}]$, we can rewrite the expectation as an integral,

$$ \mathbb{E}_{new}[S_T\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}] = \frac{S_0}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\inf}_l \exp{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\exp{(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T+\sigma\sqrt(T) x} dx\tag{2} $$

with

$$l = \frac{\ln(k/S_0)-(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$$

1. How has $(1)$ been derived? How do we go from the stock price distribution in the normal numeraire as $S_t = S_0 \exp{\{ (r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T +\sigma \sqrt{T}W_t \}}$ to $(1)$? Could this be explained in detail please as it is key to understanding how to solve these questions. I need to understand how all the moving parts bit together.
2. How has this last equality been derived? I am guessing that the $\mathbb{P}$ is different, but again I cannot see how to derive it. Moreover, could it be explained in detail as to how the $d_1$ comes into it.
3. How has this integral been derived? I cannot see where the $\exp{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ come into the integral, this seems to be some distibution from somewhere.

Comment: Please note that I have already read the books on topics such as Girsanov's theorem, change of measure, probability theory etc. I just cannot understand how all the parts fit together to answer this question

Comment: If and when you use things like change of numeraire, fundamental theorem of asset pricing, radon nikodym, please clearly state when and why you are using them

Comment: What is your understanding of a martingale?

Comment: excellent @DaneelOlivaw i have all the requisite maths, check out my math s.e. if you want to know more

Comment: To heuristically understand that change of measure with $-\sigma t$ (see the replies of Kupoc allahoui or Jan Stuller), you might know that assets divided by numéraire must be martingales. Your market, as explained by KeSchn, has actually 2 assets: the stock $S_t$ and the bank account $B_t$. You should also know that a martingale $M$ has no drift, i.e. $dM_t=0\times dt+(\dots)\times dW_t$. Now, apply Itô's Lemma to $B_t/S_t$ and ask yourself "_how should I tweak $W_t$ such that $B_t/S_t$ has no drift?_"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I provide a solution in three steps.

- The first step carefully outlines how to split up the expectation and what new measures are used. This first step does not require any special model assumption and holds in a very general framework. I derive a formula for the option price that resembles the standard Black-Scholes formula.
- In a second step, I assume that the stock price follows a geometric Brownian motion and use Girsanov's theorem to derive a precise formula for all (probabilistic) terms involved. However, I want to present a more elegant approach which does not require to integrate the Gaussian density. That's just pointlessly tedious and makes it harder to generalise the approach to other processes.
- The third section states Girsanov's theorem, links it to numéraire changes and outlines how this change impacts the drift of the stock price.

### General Numéraire Changes

As you said, the key is a numéraire change as originally outlined by [Geman et al. (1995)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3215299). The standard risk-neutral measure ($\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q^0$) uses the (locally) risk-free bank account, $B_t=e^{rt}$, as numéraire. We could easily allow for a general interest rate process $B_t=\exp\left(\int_0^t r_s\mathrm{d}s\right)$. We define a new probability measure, $\mathbb Q^1\sim\mathbb Q^0$ which uses the  stock price, $S_t$ as numéraire. The new measure, $\mathbb Q^1$, is defined via

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^1}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^0} = \frac{S_T}{S_0}\frac{B_0}{B_T}=\frac{S_T}{S_0}e^{-rT}.
\end{align*}

If the stock pays dividends at rate $\delta$, you use the reinvested stock price, $S_te^{\delta t}$, as numéraire.

The price of your option is then

\begin{align*}
e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{S_T^2-KS_T,0\}] &=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^1}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^0}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^1}\max\{S_T^2-KS_T,0\}\right] \\
&= S_0\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^1}\left[\max\{S_T-K,0\}\right] \\
&= S_0\left(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^1}[S_T\mathbb{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}] -K\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb Q^1}[\mathbb{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}]\right) \\
&= S_0\left(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^1}[S_T\mathbb{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}] -K\mathbb Q^1[\{S_T\geq K\}]\right).
\end{align*}

To compute the first expectation, we (again) use a change of numéraire. I follow this [**great paper from Mark Joshi**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637717300512). Let $N_{t,T}^\alpha$ be the time-$t$ price of an asset (claim) paying $S_T^\alpha$ at time $T$. Because of Jensen's inequality, $N_{t,T}^\alpha\neq S_t^\alpha$ if $\alpha\neq0,1$. There is of course a restriction on the choice of $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is too large, then $S_t^\alpha$ may not be integrable (in particular if your stock price model includes fat tails). So, for now we just assume that $\alpha$ is chosen appropriately. Then,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^\alpha}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^0} = \frac{N_{T,T}^\alpha B_0}{N_{0,T}^\alpha B_T} .
\end{align*}

Thus,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^\alpha}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^1} =\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^\alpha}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^0} \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb Q^0}{\mathrm d\mathbb Q^1} = \frac{N_{T,T}^\alpha B_0}{N_{0,T}^\alpha B_T} \frac{S_0B_T}{S_TB_0} =  \frac{S_{T}^\alpha}{N_{0,T}^\alpha } \frac{S_0}{S_T}.
\end{align*}

Using $\alpha=2$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E^{\mathbb Q^1}[S_T\mathbb 1_{\{S_T\geq K\}}] = \frac{N_{0,T}^2}{S_0}\mathbb E^{\mathbb Q^2}[\mathbb 1_{\{S_T\geq K\}}] =\frac{N_{0,T}^2}{S_0}\mathbb Q^2[\{S_T\geq K\}].
\end{align*}

The final option price thus reads as
$$ e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{S_T^2-KS_T,0\}] = N_{0,T}^2\mathbb Q^2[\{S_T\geq K\}] - KS_0\mathbb Q^1[\{S_T\geq K\}],$$

which beautifully resembles the Black-Scholes formula. This also hints to how a formula for the price of a general power option looks like.

### Black-Scholes Model

To actually implement the above equation, we need to find expressions for $\mathbb Q^\alpha[\{S_T\geq K\}]$ and $N_{t,T}^\alpha$. These formulae will depend on the chosen stock price model. Here, we opt for the simplest one, the Black-Scholes setting with a log-normally distributed stock price.

Let's begin with the simpler problem: the price of a claim paying $S_T^\alpha$. Using standard risk-neutral pricing and the martingale property $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W_t}|\mathcal{F}_s]=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)+\sigma W_s}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
N_{t,T}^\alpha &= e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb Q}[S_T^\alpha|\mathcal{F}_t] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb Q}\left[S_0^\alpha\exp\left(\alpha\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T+\alpha\sigma W_T \right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)}S_0^\alpha\exp\left(\alpha\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)+\sigma\alpha W_t\right) \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)}S_t^\alpha\exp\left(\alpha\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(T-t)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)\right) \\
&= S_t^\alpha \exp\left((T-t)(r(\alpha-1)+0.5\sigma^2(\alpha^2-\alpha)\right)
\end{align*}

Of course, the price $N_{t,T}^\alpha$ is log-normally distributed. By the way, using Itô's Lemma, we obtain $\mathrm{d}N_{t,T}^\alpha=rN_{t,T}^\alpha\mathrm{d}t+\alpha\sigma N_{t,T}^\alpha\mathrm{d}W_t$.

To conclude, we need to compute the exercise probability $\mathbb{Q}^\alpha[\{S_T\geq K\}]$. Under $\mathbb{Q}$, the stock price has drift $r$ and under $\mathbb Q^1$, the stock price has drift $r+\sigma^2$, see [this excellent answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/21872/41821) and [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/50502/41821) for an intuitive explanation. Under $\mathbb Q^\alpha$, the stock price has drift $r+\alpha\sigma^2$. I explain this in detail in the third section of this answer.

For now, let's accept the above drift changes. Let $S_T$ be a geometric Brownian motion under any arbitrary probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ (this could be the real world measure $\mathbb P$, the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q$ or a stock measure $\mathbb Q^\alpha$). Then, $S_T=S_0\exp\left(\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T+\sigma W_T\right)$, where $\mu$ is the drift under the respective measure $\mathcal{P}$. Thus, using that $W_T\sim N(0,T)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}[\{S_T\geq K\}] &= \mathcal{P}[\{\ln(S_T)\geq\ln(K)\}] \\
&=\mathcal{P}\left[\left\{\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T+\sigma W_T \geq -\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)\right\}\right] \\
&=\mathcal{P}\left[\left\{ Z \geq -\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)+ \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T }{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right\}\right] \\
&=1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)+ \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T }{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)\\
&=\Phi\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)+ \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T }{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right),
\end{align*}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. I used the property $\Phi(x)=1-\Phi(-x)$.

Depending on which measure we use for $\mathcal{P}$, we merely need to the right drift. For example, under $\mathbb{Q}^\alpha$, we use $r+\alpha\sigma^2$ as drift ($\mu$) of the stock price. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}^\alpha[\{S_T\geq K\}] = \Phi\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)+\left(r+\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)\sigma^2\right)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}\right).
\end{align*}

We recover the special cases $\mathbb Q^1[\{S_T\geq K\}]=\Phi(d_1)$ and  $\mathbb Q^0[\{S_T\geq K\}]=\Phi(d_2)$.

**I thoroughly recommend reading [Joshi's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637717300512) which contains more details and applications of numéraire changes, including an introductory section on the Black-Scholes model!**

### Girsanov's Theorem

I will first state Girsanov's theorem and use the change of numeraire formula to show you how to switch between two risk-neutral probability measures. Then, I'll describe how this change affects the drift of the stock price.

I cite (the one-dimensional) Girsanov theorem from [Björk's book, Theorem 12.3](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Arbitrage-Theory-Continuous-Oxford-Finance/dp/0198851618/ref=pd_lpo_14_t_0/257-2927656-5281701?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0198851618&pd_rd_r=296c5cbb-02bb-4196-91ee-654c5d50d228&pd_rd_w=EhDZ1&pd_rd_wg=l3iKU&pf_rd_p=7b8e3b03-1439-4489-abd4-4a138cf4eca6&pf_rd_r=EDXYXM4P8S826XBCA4GS&psc=1&refRID=EDXYXM4P8S826XBCA4GS). As an alternative, see [Shreve](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/0387401016/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3U70X3NOU3F6E&dchild=1&keywords=shreve%20stochastic%20calculus&qid=1594228617&s=books&sprefix=Shreve%20Stochasti%2Cstripbooks%2C144&sr=1-1) or any other textbook on stochastic calculus.

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t),\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space carrying a standard Brownian motion $W_T^\mathbb{P}$. Let $\varphi_t$ be an adapted process (``pricing kernel''). Define $\mathrm{d}L_t=\varphi_tL_t\mathrm{d}W_t^\mathbb{P}$ with $L_0=1$ such that $L_t=\exp\left(\int_0^t \varphi_s\mathrm{d}W_s^\mathbb{P}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \varphi_s^2\mathrm{d}s\right)=\mathcal{E}\left(\int_0^t \varphi_s\mathrm{d}W_s^\mathbb{P}\right)$. Assume that $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[L_T]=1$. We define a new probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\mathcal{F}_T$ via $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm d\mathbb{P}}=L_T$. Then, $\mathrm{d}W_t^\mathbb{P}=\varphi_t\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t^\mathbb{Q}$ where $W^\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion.

Here $\mathcal{E}$ is the [Doléans-Dade exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential). For the sake of completeness, I repeat the change of numéraire formula. Let $B_t$ be the price of our standard numéraire (bank account) with probability measure $\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q^0$. Let $N_t$ be the price process of a new numéraire. The corresponding martingale measure $\mathbb{Q}^N$ is defined via
$$ \frac{\mathrm d\mathbb{Q}^N}{\mathrm d \mathbb{Q}} = \frac{N_TB_0}{N_0B_T}. $$

**Example 1**: let $B_t=e^{rt}$ and $N_t=S_t$. This means we switch from the standard risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q^0$ to the stock measure $\mathbb Q^1$. Thus, $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}^1}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}^0} = \frac{S_T}{S_0e^{rT}} =e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T+\sigma W_T^{\mathbb Q^0}}=\mathcal{E}(\sigma W_T^{\mathbb Q^0})$. I use a superscript to highlight that $W_t^{\mathbb Q^0}$ is a standard Brownian motion with respect to the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^0$. In the sense of Girsanov's theorem, $\varphi_t \equiv\sigma$. Thus, $\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^0}=\sigma \mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^1}$. This agrees with what Gordon derived [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/21872/41821) (he called the new Brownian motion $\hat{W_t}$ instead of $W_t^{\mathbb Q^1}$).

**Example 2**: let $B_t=e^{rt}$ and the new numéraire is $N_{t,T}^\alpha$, the time-$t$ price of an asset paying $S_T^\alpha$ at time $T$. Thus, $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}^0} = \frac{S_T^\alpha}{S_0^\alpha e^{rT}} =e^{-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2 T+\alpha\sigma W_T^{\mathbb Q^0}}=\mathcal{E}(\alpha\sigma W_T^{\mathbb Q^0})$. In the sense of Girsanov's theorem, $\varphi_T \equiv\alpha\sigma$. Thus, $\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^0}=\alpha\sigma \mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^\alpha}$.

Okay, starting with the numéraire change, we could use Girsanov's theorem to change a Brownian motion between the two probability measures. How does now the drift of the stock change?

Well, under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q^0$, we have $\mathrm{d}S_t=rS_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^0}$. And we are now able to express $\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^0}$ under the new measure $\mathbb{Q}^1$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=rS_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^0} \\
&=rS_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\left( \sigma \mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^1}\right) \\
&=(r+\sigma^2)S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^1}.
\end{align*}

Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S_t&=rS_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^0} \\
&=rS_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\left( \alpha\sigma \mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^\alpha}\right) \\
&=(r+\alpha\sigma^2)S_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma S_t\mathrm{d}W_t^{\mathbb Q^\alpha}.
\end{align*}

Here we go. The drift of the stock price under the standard risk-neutral measure is $r$ and under a stock measure, $\mathbb Q^\alpha$, this drift changes to $r+\alpha\sigma^2$.

Comment: Im struggling a bit with this. Joshi's papers has too many unexplained equations, with the detail glossed over.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W_t}|\mathcal{F}_s]=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)+\sigma W_s}$ where does this come from?

Comment: This method is attractive though

Comment: @Permian It comes from the fact that $X_t=e^{\sigma W_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}$ is a martingale, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_s$

Comment: The point of my answer is to give you a more elegant approach for which you don't need to complete many tedious integrals. In particular, the formulae are easy to generalise. What I like the most about this approach is that it applies the change of numeraire twice. So, this may help you better understand how to apply it. Let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W_t}|\mathcal{F}_s]=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)+\sigma W_s}$ no sorry I still cannot see how this has been derived

Comment: "he stock price in the Black-Scholes model has drift $r+\sigma^2$". How can you spot this? I dont understand the linked answers at all. After this point you have lost me

Comment: I cant see the exact way Girsanov has been applied either. To be honest, the whole paragraph from "To conclude...Bjork" is hard to understand

Comment: $= e^{-r(T-t)}S_t^\alpha\exp\left(\alpha\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(T-t)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)\right)$. I cant see how you have pulled the $S_t$ here either

Comment: @Permian If $X_t=e^{\sigma W_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}$ is a martingale, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}|\mathcal{F}_s]=e^{\sigma W_s-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2s}$. Now, you can take the exponential $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}$ out of the conditional expectation and bring it on the right side, right?

Comment: @Permian In the BS world, $S_t=S_0e^{(r-0.5\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}$ and $S_t^\alpha=S_0^\alpha e^{(r-0.5\sigma^2)\alpha t+\alpha\sigma W_t}$. So, you only need to collect these terms to obtain $S_t^\alpha$ in the equations in my answer and that's it. The $\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)$ remains unaffected and the rest is summarised as $S_t^\alpha$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Permian Let me know whether you are okay with the two points above. They were really only little maths manipulations. No tricks or such. I can provide a thorough edit to my answer and add more details to Girsanov's theorem. Just let me know whether there's anything else that you don't understand in my answer (other than this one paragraph on Girsanov). If you tell me how I can help you, I'll edit the answer accordingly :)

Comment: I get the points above now thanks, its only the bit around girsanov that I dont get now

Comment: @Permian That's great to hear. Please have a look at the information I added. I started from the statement of the theorem and outlined how it impacts the drift of the stock price. Please ask further questions if I couldn't answer everything

Comment: $\mathcal{P}[\{S_T\geq K\}]=N\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)+\mu T-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)$. Last thing. How has this been derived?

Comment: that needs to go in the answer, for everyone else

Comment: i think you forget how much you know at times

Comment: @Kevin: why is it that we chose $N^α_{t,T}$ as the time-t price of an asset (claim) paying $S^α_T$ at time $T$? Why not chose $N_t \equiv S_t^2$, such that $\frac{dQ^2}{dQ^1} = \frac{S_T}{S_0}$ and $E^{Q^1}[S_T 1_{(.)}] = S_0 E^{Q^2}[ 1_{(.)}]$?

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz great question. The problem is that $e^{-rt}S_t^2$ is not a martingale (Jensen’s inequality). The price (value) process, $N_{t,T}^\alpha$, is however (by construction). Remember that a numéraire is defined to be the _price_ of an asset (which is the unit for the price of all other assets).

Answer (score 4):

It's just Girsanov's theorem.
I suppose that under the risk neutral measure Q

$$dS_{t}= r S_{t} dt + \sigma S_{t}dW_{t},$$ $$S_{t} = S_{0}\exp\left((r-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})T + \sigma W_{T}\right)$$
By multiplying by $e^{-rT}$ I have $e^{-rT}S_{T}$ which is a martingale so that I can change my measure under $Q$ to some equivalent probabilty $Q_{1}$ under which $ W_{t}^{'} = W_{t} - \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s}ds = W_{t}-\sigma t $ is a $ Q_{1}$ Brownian motion from Girsanov's theorem, now $S_{T}$ writes: $$S_0 \exp\left((r-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})T + \sigma W_{T}^{'} + \sigma^{2} T\right) = S_0 \exp\left((r+\frac{\sigma ^{2}}{2})T + \sigma W_{T}^{'}\right)$$

So, $$\frac{C_{0}}{S_{0}} = E^{Q^{1}}[\max(S_{T}-K,0)]$$
and you have: $$\mathbb{E}^{Q_{1}}[\max(S_T-K,0)] = \mathbb{E}^{Q_{1}}[S_T\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}] - \mathbb{E}^{Q_{1}}[K\mathbb{I}_{S_T>K}]$$

Comment: $e^{-rT}S_{T}$ how do you know this is a martingale?

Comment: $ W_{T}^{'}$ how do you know this is $N(0,1)$?

Comment: $ \mathbb{P}(S_T > K) = N(d_1)$ how has this been derived?

Comment: $W_{t}^{'} = W_{t} - \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s}ds$ where did this come from?

Comment: @Permian $e^{-rt}S_t$ is a $Q$-martingale _by definition_. $W_T'$ is a Brownian motion and by definition normally distributed (but _not_ standard normal!!). $\mathbb P(S_T>K)=N(d_1)$ is also wrong, we have $Q(S_T>K)=N(d_2)$ and $Q^1(S_T>K)=N(d_1)$, both follow from simple integration. Finally, $W_t'=W_t+\int_0^t\sigma_sds$ comes from Girsanov's theorem...

Comment: $Q(S_T>K)=N(d_2)$, $Q^1(S_T>K)=N(d_1)$, where did these come from? @Alex

Comment: @Permian You just need to integrate the density of a log-normally distributed random variable

Comment: @Alex ill look again tomorrow. thanks for the help.

Comment: $Q^1(S_T>K)=N(d_1)$ I still cant see this, what distribution am I integrating over? @Alex

Comment: You know that $S_{t} = S_{0}\exp\left((r-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})T + \sigma W_{T}\right)$ which is the same in law as $S_{t} =  S_{0}\exp\left((r-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})T + \sigma \sqrt(T) \mathcal{N}(0,1)}\right)$ so you can modify the event $\{ S_{T} > K \}$  as something of the form $\{ N(0,1) > d_[1} \{$ and after that it's just your typical normal CDF. :o , i don't know your maths level but these are some very basic questions when introducing stochastic calculus . You may want to check out some courses online before going into quantitative finance.

Answer (score 3):

Black scholes formula based on $S_t$ measure , theory, and formulas you mention are derived in detail in "Steven Shreve: Stochastic Calculus and Finance" draft pdf from 1997 , page 328 "stock price as numeraire".

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1** is answered in parts 1 through to 6: the idea is that each part slowly builds the tools required to derive the process equation for $S_t$ under the $S_t$ Numeraire.

**Question 2** & **Question 3** are then answered in part 7.

- **Part 1: Expectation of a function of a Random variable**:

Let $X(t)$ be some generic Random Variable with probability density function given by $f_{X_t}(h)$, where $h$ is a "dummy" variable. Let $g(X_t)$ be some (well-behaved) function of $X_t$. Then (I am stating the below without proof):

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_t)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(X_t)f_{X_t}(h)dh$$

- **Part 2: Radon-Nikodym Derivative**:

Let $\mathbb{P^1}$ be a Probability measure defined via the Probability Density Function of some random variable $X_t$:

$$\mathbb{P^1}(A):=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X_t}(h)dh$$

For all events $\{A: X_t \leq a\}$.

Radon-Nikodym derivative is implicitly defined as some Random-Variable (let's call it $Y_t$) that satisfies the following:

$$ \mathbb{P^2}(A) = \mathbb{E^{P^1}}[Y_t \mathbb{I_{\{ A\}}}] $$.

The above definition becomes more intuitive with a specific example: let $X_t$ be a standard Brownian Motion, i.e. $X_t:=W_t$, and let $Y_t:=e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}$. Basically $Y_t=g(W_t)$, where $g()$ is a well-behaved function: so we can make use of the result in **part 1**, specifically:

$$ \mathbb{E^{P^1}}[Y_t \mathbb{I_{\{ A\}}}] = \mathbb{E^{P^1}}[g(W_t) \mathbb{I_{\{ A\}}}] = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(X_t)f_{X_t}(h) \mathbb{I_{ \{ W_t \leq a \}}}dh = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{a}g(X_t)f_{X_t}(h)dh = \\ =  \int_{-\infty}^{a}e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma h}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-h^2}{2t}}dh = \\ =\int_{h=-\infty}^{h=k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(h^2-\sigma t)}{2t}}dh $$

(To go from the penultimate line to the last line, we just need to complete the square).

**The main point**: by applying the definition $\mathbb{P^2}(A) = \mathbb{E^{P^1}}[Y_t \mathbb{I_{\{ A\}}}]$, we can see how $Y_t$ "creates" a new probability measure: under $\mathbb{P^2}$, the same event, specifically $A: W_t \leq a$ has an altered  probability, compared to the same event under $\mathbb{P^1}$.

By inspecting the probability $\mathbb{P^2}(A)=\mathbb{P^2}(W_t \leq a) = \int_{h=-\infty}^{h=k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(h^2-\sigma t)}{2t}}dh$, we ca see that what was standard Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P^1}$ now has a probability distribution of a Brownian motion with a drift: so under $\mathbb{P^2}$, $W_t$ is no longer a standard Brownian motion, but a Brownian motion with drift $\sigma t$.

- **Part 3: Cameron-Martin-Girsanov Theorem**:

The theorem states that:

If $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion under some $\mathbb{P^1}$, then there exists some $\mathbb{P^2}$ under which $W_t$ is a Brownian motion with drift $\mu t$. The Radon-Nikodym derivative to get us from $\mathbb{P^1}$ to $\mathbb{P^2}$ is:

$$ \frac{d \mathbb{P^2}}{d \mathbb{P^1}}(t)= e^{-0.5\mu^2t+\mu W_t}$$

If $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t + \mu t$ is a Brownian motion with some drift $\mu t$ under some $\mathbb{P^1}$, then there exists some $\mathbb{P^2}$ under which $\tilde{W_t}$ is a standard Brownian motion (i.e. no drift). The Radon-Nikodym derivative to get us from $\mathbb{P^1}$ to $\mathbb{P^2}$ is:

$$ \frac{d \mathbb{P^2}}{d \mathbb{P^1}}(t)= e^{+0.5\mu^2t-\mu W_t}$$

We basically "proved" the C-M-G theorem in **part 2** above.

- **Part 4: Numeraire and Probability Measures**

Under the risk-neutral measure, with deterministic money market as Numeraire, the stock price process is: $S_t=S_0exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma W(t) \right]$. **The only source of randomness in this process is $W_t$**, which is a standard Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P^Q}$ associated with the Numeraire $N_t:=e^{rt}$.

Since $W_t$ is the only source of randomness, this gives us an idea of how a change of probability measure will work for the process $S_t$: the change of measure will be driven via a Radon-Nikodym derivative **applied to $W_t$.** If we can somehow get a Radon-Nikodym derivative that resembles the one from the C-M-G Theorem, then we're in for an easy change of measure: we could apply the CMG theorem directly to $W_t$ in the process equation for $S_t$!!

- **Part 5: Change of Numeraire formula**

Without proof, if we want to change numeraire from $N_t$ to some $N^{2}_t$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative we need to use is:

$$ \frac{dN^{2}_t}{dN_t}:= \frac{N(t_0)N_2(t)}{N(t)N_2(t_0)} $$

**(The proof of the above formula can be found here: [Change of Numeraire formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/change-of-numeraire-formula))**

- **Part 6: Choosing $S_t$ as Numeraire**

Applying the formula from **part 5** above, we get:

$$ \frac{dN^{S_t}_t}{dN_t}:= \frac{N(t_0)N^{S_t}(t)}{N(t)N^{S_t}(t_0)} = \\= \frac{1*S_t}{e^{rt}S_0}= \\ = \frac{S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma W(t) \right]}{e^{rt}S_0}= e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t} $$

The above result is great news, because we can use **part 3** directly and apply $e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}$ as Radon-Nikodym derivative to $W_t$: we know this will introduce the drift $\sigma t$ under the probability measure defined through $\frac{dN^{S_t}_t}{dN_t}=e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}$.

Let $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t-\sigma t$ be a Brownian motion with a drift equal to $-\sigma t$ under $\mathbb{P^Q}$. Inserting $\tilde{W_t}$ into the process equation for $S_t$ under $\mathbb{P^Q}$, we get (pure algebraic manipulation, no tricks here):

$$S_t=S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma W(t) \right]= \\ = S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma (\tilde{W}(t)+\sigma t)  \right] = \\ = S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma^2 t + \tilde{W}(t)  \right] = \\ = S_0\exp\left[ (r+0.5 \sigma^2)t+ \tilde{W}(t)  \right]$$

The above equation is not particularly useful in any way. But we can now do the following: we can apply the Cameron-Martin-Girsanov theorem to $\tilde{W}_t$, which is very convenient: taking the Radon-Nikodym drivative $\frac{dN^{S_t}_t}{dN_t}=e^{-0.5\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t}$ and applying it to $\tilde{W_t}$ will add the drift $\sigma t$. But $\tilde{W_t}$ has negative drift equal to $-\sigma t$. Therefore, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dN^{S_t}_t}{dN_t}$ will "kill" the drift of $\tilde{W_t}$. Consequently, under the probability measure associated with $S_t$ as Numeraire, $\tilde{W_t}$ becomes a standard Brownian motion with no drift.

That's why under the Stock numeraire, the process for the stock price becomes (with $\tilde{W}_t$ being a standard Brownian motion):

$$S_t=S_0\exp\left[ (r+0.5 \sigma^2)t+ \tilde{W}(t)  \right]$$

It is worth noting that often people use "lazy" notation and don't put the 'tilde' sign on the Brownian motion under the new measure: but I prefer to do it to emphasize that it's a different process to the plain Brownian motion $W_t$ under the risk-neutral measure.

**Part 7: evaluating $\mathbb{E^{N_{S}}}[S_t\mathbb{I_{\{S_t > k\}}}]$**:

I think there are multiple ways the expectation can be evaluated. The method that uses the least advanced mathematics but involves the most labor is direct evaluation via an integral:

$$ \mathbb{E^{N_{S}}}[S_t\mathbb{I_{\{S_t > k\}}}] = \int_{S_t=k}^{\infty} S_t f_{S_t}(S_t)dS_t = \int_{h=k}^{\infty} h f_{S_t}(h)dh $$

We know that $S_t$ is log-normally distributed, so we know the density of $S_t$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution):

$$f_{S_t}(h)= \frac{1} {h \sqrt{t}\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(ln(h/S_0)-(r-0.5\sigma^2)t)^2}{2\sigma^2t}}$$

Plugging this into the integral results in the cancellation of the $h$ in the first denominator:

$$\int_{h=k}^{\infty} \frac{1} {\sqrt{t}\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(ln(h/S_0)-(r-0.5\sigma^2)t)^2}{2\sigma^2t}}dh $$

I am gonna do the following substitutions: $y:=ln(h/S_0)$, so that $h=S_0e^e$, $dh=S_0e^ydy$, and when $h=K$, we get $y=ln\left( \frac{K}{S_0} \right)$.

Integrating via substitution then yields:

$$\int_{y=ln(K/S_0)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{(y-(r-0.5\sigma^2)t)^2}{2\sigma^2t}}S_0 e^y dy$$

I am now gonna simplify the notation further with: $\tilde{\mu}:=(r-0.5\sigma^2)t$ and $\tilde{\sigma}:=\sigma \sqrt{t}$, so the integral becomes:

$$\int_{y=ln(K/S_0)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\tilde{\sigma}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{(y-\tilde{\mu})^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}}S_0 e^y dy$$

Completing the square between $e^y$ and $e^{\frac{(y-\tilde{\mu})^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}}$ gives:

$$ \exp(y) \exp\left(\frac{(y-\tilde{\mu})^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}\right) = \\ = \exp \left(\frac{(y-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}))^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}\right)*\exp\left(\tilde{\mu}+0.5\tilde{\sigma}^2\right) = \\ =\exp \left(\frac{(y-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}))^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}\right)*\exp\left(rt\right) $$

The last line uses the fact that $\tilde{\mu}+0.5\tilde{\sigma}^2=(rt-0.5\sigma^2t)+0.5\sigma^2t=rt$.

Plugging back into the integral gives:

$$S_0e^{rt}\int_{y=ln(K/S_0)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\tilde{\sigma}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(\frac{(y-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}))^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}\right)dy$$

Finally, one last substitution: I will take $z:=\frac{y-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}^2)}{\sqrt{t}\sigma}$, which gives $dy=\sqrt{t}\sigma dz$. Furthermore, when $y=ln\left( \frac{K}{S_0} \right)$, we get:

$$z=\frac{ln\left( \frac{K}{S_0} \right)-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}^2)}{\sqrt{t}\sigma}=\frac{ln\left( \frac{K}{S_0} \right)-(rt+0.5 \sigma^2t)}{\sqrt{t}\sigma} = \\ = (-1) \frac{ln\left( \frac{S_0}{K} \right)+rt+0.5 \sigma^2t}{\sqrt{t}\sigma} = -d_1 $$

So plugging this last substitution for $y$ into the integral gives:

$$S_0e^{rt}\int_{y=ln(K/S_0)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\tilde{\sigma}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp \left(\frac{(y-(\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\sigma}))^2}{2\tilde{\sigma}^2}\right)dy= \\ = S_0e^{rt}\int_{z=-d_1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp \left(\frac{z^2}{2} \right)dz= \\ =S_0e^{rt}\mathbb{P}(Z>-d_1)=S_0e^{rt}\mathbb{P}(Z \leq d_1) = S_0e^{rt} N(d_1) $$

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for. Will try to get full understanding by this evening

Comment: I think there are more elegant ways to evaluate $\mathbb{E^{N_{S}}}[S_t\mathbb{I_{\{S_t > k\}}}]$, but the above requires the most basic mathematics. The expense paid is the lengthy algebra.

Comment: I'm not bothered by the maths per se, it's more how to fit the pieces together in a finance setting

Comment: $\frac{d \mathbb{P^2}}{d \mathbb{P^1}}(t)= e^{-0.5\mu^2t+\mu W_t}$ (first equation of part 3). I cant see why this isnt $-\mu W_t$. I have the general form of girsanovs theorem from here, https://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/~tobias/Class416/Lecture07.pdf page 4

Comment: The signs on the equation after that look funny to me as well

Comment: Why are we looking at $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t+\sigma t$ but $\tilde{W_t}:=W_t-\sigma t$ in part 6?

Comment: we can apply the Cameron-Martin-Girsanov theorem to $\tilde{W_t}$. Not sure what this means exactly. In fact the whole paragraph starting "The above equation is not particularly useful in any way." is hard to understand

Comment: @Permian: ad1: if the sign was $-\mu W_t$, the Radon-Nikodym would add negative drift. The way I defined the sign means it adds positive drift. In the paper you attach, they define $\tilde{W}_t=W_t+\mu t$, so their Radon-Nikodym removes the drift (adds negative drift) to make it a Standard Brownian Motion.

Comment: @Permian: ad2: $\tilde{W}_t$ in part 3 is unrelated to $\tilde{W}_t$ in part 6. I just use the tilde notation to *define* a new process in the respective parts to distinguish it from plain $W_t$. In part 3, I defined $\tilde{W}_t$ by adding $\mu t$ to $W_t$ just to illustrate that the Radon-Nikdym derivative can add as well as remove a drift, depending on how you define the Radon-Nikdym.

Comment: you assume in part 2 that $f_{X_t}(h) = {\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-h^2}{2t}}$. how can i assume that this will be work in the general case?

Comment: Im going to look again tomorrow. I dont understnad why this is so hard

Comment: Assuming $f_{X_t}(h) = {\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-h^2}{2t}}$: good question. This is always the case with Standard Brownian Motion. That's why we like defining process equations via Standard Brownian Motion. So that we can apply the CMG theorem to $W_t$ which has the given distribution. If your process equation would ever contain a different source or randomness than plain $W_t$, you would indeed (as you point out) have difficulty applying the CMG theorem.

Comment: That's why under the Stock numeraire... how was the equation after this derived?

Comment: @Permian: I derived it via substituting $\tilde{W}_t:=W_t-\sigma t$ in the paragraph above. An alternative way: take the equation for $S_t$ under $N^{Q}$: $S_t=S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma W(t) \right]$. Apply Radon-Nikdym to $W_t$: that moves you from $N^Q$ to $N^{S_t}$. Under the new measure $N^{S_t}$, $W_t$ is no longer a Standard Brownian motion, but a Brownian with a drift. So it can be rewritten as $Z_t + \sigma t$, where $Z_t$ is Standard Brownian under the new measure $N^{S_t}$. So we get: $S_t=S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma (Z(t) + \sigma t) \right]$.

Comment: @Permian: multiplying out the term $\sigma(Z(t)+\sigma t)$ gives: $S_0\exp\left[ (r-0.5 \sigma^2)t+\sigma^2 t + Z(t)  \right] = S_0\exp\left[ (r+0.5 \sigma^2)t+ Z(t)  \right]$. So we now have the process equation for $S_t$ under $N^{S_t}$ where $Z_t$ is a Standard Brownian Motion under $N^{S_t}$. Basically, I changed the notation from $\tilde{W}_t$ to $Z_t$ in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: Your part 3 implies that a theorem in one direction, but you have applied it in the reverse direction, which implies some kind of equivalence